# html image slide show for multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, image, slideshow

I've just got stuck with creating a Image slider. This image slider Shell be handling different Images for each Event. But at the Moment even the slider is not working for one.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "/images/AchernerBogenclubTitel.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/P1220966.JPG" < /script>
```

```html
<div class="boxInner" class="bw pic">
  <img src="/images/turnierbilder/2015/LMH2015_SGVillingen_markus_norbert.jpg" name="slide" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 1;

    function slideit() {
      document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src");
      if (step < 2)
        step++;
      else
        step = 1;
      setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
    }
    slideit();
  </script>
```

both of my codes are in the same file.

I also tried to use a different apoache:

```html
<td>
  <center>
    <p style="font-size:12px ">
      <a href="/docs/landesmeisterschafthallesbsv2015.pdf">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <!-->
          var image1 = new Image()
           image1.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220967.jpg"
          var image2 = new Image()
           image2.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220971.jpg"
          var image3 = new Image()
           image3.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220973.jpg"
          var image4 = new Image()
           image4.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220977.jpg"
          var image5 = new Image()
           image5.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220985.jpg"
            //-->
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
          <img name="slide" width="310" height="222">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var step = 1

            function slideit() {
              document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
              if (step < 5)
                step++
                else
                  step = 1
              setTimeout("slideit()", 5000)
            }
            slideit()
              //-->
          </script>
```

This one works realy nicely but i seem to not be able to get it to work on multiple Groups on the same page (id rather use this Code if there is a way to fix the issue)

Comment: "document.images.slide" what did ou try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have en error of comprehension about selector, try this :

```
    <div class="boxInner" class="bw pic">
        <img src="" id="slide" />
    </div>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
  var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "http://www.louisetzeliemartin.org/medias/images/chat-1.jpg";
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "https://static.mediapart.fr/files/2016/01/30/chat.jpg";
   var step = 1;

    function slideit() {
      document.getElementById('slide').src = eval("image" + step + ".src");
      if (step < 2)
        step++;
      else
        step = 1;
      setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
    }
    slideit();
</script>
```

Version with array :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >


  var image1 = new Image();
    image1.src = "http://www.louisetzeliemartin.org/medias/images/chat-1.jpg";


var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "https://static.mediapart.fr/files/2016/01/30/chat.jpg";

var images = [image1,image2];//here i create an array "images" with two elements "image1" and "image2"

   var step = 0;//step is now 0 because 1st index of an array is 0

    function slideit() {
      document.getElementById('slide').src = images[step].src;//i want read index n of my array
      if (step < (images.length-1))//lenght give number of element in this array
        step++;
      else
        step = 0;
      setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
    }
    slideit();
</script>
```

Version with 2 images :

```
 <div class="boxInner" class="bw pic">
        <img src="" id="slide1" />
        <img src="" id="slide2" />
    </div>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "http://www.louisetzeliemartin.org/medias/images/chat-1.jpg";


var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "https://static.mediapart.fr/files/2016/01/30/chat.jpg";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "http://media.virginradio.fr/article-2505914-fb-f1415609183/chat-mignon-petit-chaton-therapie-detente.jpg";


var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = "http://media.meltydiscovery.fr/article-2927858-fb/chat-chaton-chats-biso-le-caire-egypte-metro.jpg";


var images = [image1,image2,image3,image4];

   var step = 0;//step is now 0 because 1st index of an array is 0

    function slideit() {
      document.getElementById('slide1').src = images[step].src;
      document.getElementById('slide2').src = images[step+1].src;
      if (step < (images.length-1)/2)
        step=step+2;
      else
        step = 0;
      setTimeout("slideit()", 2000);
    }
    slideit();
</script>
```

Comment: Furthermore, why you dont store image in array ? eval("image" + step + ".src"); is not a good practice

Comment: What is an array?  And for what do u use it?

Comment: And how ulwould u use it for different photo group slideshow?

Comment: Check this : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp "JavaScript arrays are used to store multiple values in a single variable."  and look at my edit (second code block)

Comment: Thank you. There is only one thing left how would u do it if u had to group 6 images into 2 groups and make it like a slideshow

Comment: I have edited with another version, please consider to accept this answer if i help you.

Comment: so if i understand the Code right the first and second Image are together and third and fourth are a Group?