# html image sldeshow not changing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

ive scripted my self a Image slideshowthere is just the issue that the slideshow stays static on the first Image for each Group.
this Code here is where i have all my Images and then they get selected from it.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  <!-->
  var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220967.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220971.jpg"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220973.jpg"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220977.jpg"
var image5 = new Image()
image5.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220985.jpg"
  //-->
  < /script>
```

and the second part is where the JavaScript should creat the slideshow.

```js
<img src="LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220967.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="slide" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<3)
            step++
        else
            step=1
        setTimeout("slideit()",3000)
    }
    slideit()
</script>

<img src="LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220977.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="slide" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=4
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<5)
            step++
        else
            step=4
        setTimeout("slideit()",3000)
    }
    slideit()
</script>
```

I hope that there is an easy way of Fixing this Problem and that the way i was having it with the Images still could be left to make it a bit easier is view the Code :D
mark

Comment: why aren't you using simple image array for slideshow

Comment: two seperate `<script>`tags mean two seperate scripts. I doubt the second script has access to the first script's variables.

Comment: yes i want them to be diffentent slideshows so i can place them on different Points on the same page but with different Images.

Comment: oh ok you didn't mention this... but in the second snippet's functions you are calling those variables `image1.src` and `image4.src`? to me it looked like you were trying to use the varaible you defined in the first snippet.

Comment: I'm not trying to ask you something I'm trying to tell you something. `document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src")` tries to eval `image4.src` if I'm not mistaken. You defined `var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "LMH2015_SGVillingen_P1220977.jpg"` in the first script. To the last script `image4.src` is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html image slide show for multiple images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648652/html-image-slide-show-for-multiple-images)

Comment: so how would i then chang the script that image1-3 are in the first slide Show and Image 4-5 in the second one but that i could extend it by asmany Image slideshow as i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below function and it is dynamic just call the function with array image and duration.

HTML

```
<img src="" width="300" height="300" name="slide" />
```

JS

```
 var imageArr = ["http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Beauty-of-nature-random-4884759-1280-800.jpg", "http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Free-Wallpaper-Nature-Scenes.jpg", "http://www.viralnovelty.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/121.jpg"];
 function slideShow(imageName, imgArray, duration) {//pass image array and time duration
    if(imgArray.constructor !== Array) {
      alert("proovide valid image array for slide show");
      return false;
     }
     var step=0;
     setInterval(function(){
       if(step > imgArray.length - 1){
          step = 0; //reset count when the last image 
       }
       document.images[imageName].src = imgArray[step];
       step++;
      }, duration);
  }
 slideshow('slide', imageArr, 5000);//call the function with image name
```

demo link: [Slideshow](https://jsfiddle.net/o98nL5r4/2/)

Comment: thank you for the beautifull slideshow but where do i insert the Images and it will not conflict with an additional slideshow on the same html page?

Comment: just create image array as I have created above (imageArr) and pass it in function.

Comment: I have updated the function. just pass the image name and it will work for other slideshow also

Comment: so i put the Java and html Code in the same file?

Comment: yes, you can put. also you can check my updated fiddle. I have added two slide show using same function.

Comment: thank you verry much. there is just the issue i dont know how to insert JavaScript into a html file .:(

Comment: just put the above code in between <script> </script> tag above closing body tag.